# Vector to raster by maximum combined area

Tags: qgis, raster, vector-grid, rasterization

I need to convert a polygon to raster resulting in a raster with cell size of 250 meters and each cell value takes the value of the objects, with equal values, that together sum the largest surface inside a cell. In ArcGIS, there is an option to use the maximum combined area algorithm within the feature to raster tool but now, I do not have ArcGIS installed.

Can it be done using QGIS?

I just want to get something like that:

[image: Maximum Combined Area[1]]

Comment: If you need to also ask about Python then do that in a separate question and specify the Python library.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of a specific function within QGIS or a Python script that will do the task that you ask, but you could develop a work around through several steps.

Conceptually, you could convert your polygon layer to a raster layer at a much finer spatial resolution (for example 5 x 5 m). You could then use the GRASS function `r.mode` within QGIS to resample the layer at your desired spatial resolution (250 x 250 m), which will reassign the upsampled pixel value the most commonly (i.e., maximum combined area) found value.

Depending on if you need the value of the resampled raster to actually be meaningful, you could potentially do some other manipulations to get it to the maximum combined area.